# Magento 1.9 : Additional Dropdown in Massaction

Tags: magento-1.9, massaction

How to Add Additional Drop-down in Mass-action.

Example if I select Delete in Mass-action it also Ask Reason in another Drop-down for Delete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create a small extension ...

1. Add this to you `config.xml`

   ```
   <adminhtml>
       <events>
           <adminhtml_block_html_before>
               <observers>
                   <your_handle>
                       <type>singleton</type>
                       <class>[model]/observer</class>
                       <method>addMassactionToProductGrid</method>
                   </your_handle>
               </observers>
           </adminhtml_block_html_before>
       </events>
   </adminhtml>
   ```
2. and for your `Observer.php`

   ```
   public function addMassactionToProductGrid($observer)
   {
       $block = $observer->getBlock();
       if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid) {
           $attributes = ...

           $block->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
               'my_massaction',
               array(
                   'label'      => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Update Attribute Values'),
                   'url'        => $block->getUrl('*/*/mycontrolleraction', array('_current' => true)),
                   # this add the additional dropdown
                   'additional' => array(
                       'attribute' => array(
                           'name'   => 'attribute',
                           'type'   => 'select',
                           'class'  => 'required-entry',
                           'label'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Delete Reason'),
                           'values' => array(
                               array(
                                   'value' => 'Some Value',
                                   'label' => 'Your Label'
                               )
                           )
                       )
                   )
               )
           );
       }

       return $this;
   }
   ```

**Note:** this example is for admin product grid, but it should work for other grids too. Just change `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` to you grid type.